# Is possible to look up all static imported classes?

Tags: groovy

This is only for a report generating tool!

I would like to look all static imported values, the classLoader doesn't contain it.

example:

MyTestEnum.groovy

```
package org.example

enum MyTestEnum {
   TEST_1,
   TEST_2,
   TEST_3
}
```

MyService.groovy

```
package org.example

import static org.example.TEST_1
import static org.example.TEST_3

class MyService {
 
   MyTestEnum getTest1() {
       return TEST_1
   }

   MyTestEnum getTest3() {
       return TEST_3
   }
}


class SomeClass {

   void printMagic() {
      MyService.classLoader.somemagic
   }

}
```

Comment: What's the goal of this? In theory java decompiler able to do this. Probably it's possible to do ast-transformation in groovy. But all this not an easy path...

Comment: The purpose is documentation auto documentation. The plan is to do it through Spock.